# Плавное изменение размеров блока, в котором изменяется количество символов по клику на кнопку "подробнее"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Есть блок, у которого по клику изменяется количество символов, соответственно изменяется и размер блока, но transition работать не хочет, как исправить?

```js
  $(function() {
    $(".parent .text p").each(function() {
      $(this).data('full', $(this).html());
      $(this).html($(this).html().substr(0, 70));

    });


    $(".parent .rmore").click(function() {
      $(this).parents(".parent").toggleClass("active");
      $(this).toggleClass("act");

      if ($(this).is(".act")) {
        $(this).html("cвернуть");
        $(this).siblings('.text').find('p').html($(this).siblings('.text').find('p').data('full'));
      } else {
        $(this).html("подробнее...");
        $(this).siblings('.text').find('p').html($(this).siblings('.text').find('p').html().substr(0, 70));
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
  .rmore {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #F8BBD0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .parent {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #F1F1F1;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px;
    transition: 700ms;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">
      Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный
      эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия. Не следует, однако забывать, что сложившаяся
      структура организации способствует подготовки и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat possimus voluptas officiis est odio porro corporis reiciendis consequuntur laboriosam ad quae numquam impedit, a animi, consectetur inventore minus eveniet nam!
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {

  var h = '20px';


  $(".parent .text p").each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.data('h', that.height());
    that.height(h);
  });


  $(".parent .rmore").click(function() {

    var that = $(this);

    that.parents(".parent").toggleClass("active");
    that.toggleClass("act");

    if (that.is(".act")) {
      that.html("cвернуть");
      that.siblings('.text').find('p').animate({
        height: that.siblings('.text').find('p').data('h')
      }, 200);
    } else {
      that.html("подробнее...");
      that.siblings('.text').find('p').animate({
        height: h
      }, 200);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rmore {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #F8BBD0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  transition: 700ms;
}
.parent > .text > p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">

      Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации дальнейших направлений развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий представляет собой интересный
      эксперимент проверки новых предложений. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки систем массового участия. Не следует, однако забывать, что сложившаяся
      структура организации способствует подготовки и реализации позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="text-justify">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat possimus voluptas officiis est odio porro corporis reiciendis consequuntur laboriosam ad quae numquam impedit, a animi, consectetur inventore minus eveniet nam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, architecto, est. Repellat ullam placeat, suscipit cupiditate inventore quis nostrum nemo molestiae nam, et, odit labore laudantium obcaecati aspernatur veritatis voluptatum?</p>

  </div>
  <div class="rmore">подробнее...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: кажется нормального варианта нет, потому что межстрочный интервал может быть разный а еще в строке может быть разный размер шрифта, и что для одного блока 20рх хорошо, то для другого - кривая обрезка. Смотрите, тут к родительскому и так класс active крепится, я бы мог написать так: `.parent p{ height: 20px; transition: 1s} .parent.active p{ height: auto}`. и это тоже работало бы

Comment: изначально сам ведь думал этот вариант применять как более простой, но он оказался неуниверсальным... Нельзя резать текст с помощью css